# How can i get a zero in front of the week number when it is a one-digit number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to get the week number, and I did using `DATEPAR(WEEK,DATE)` , however, one-digit week numbers do not come with a zero in front.

Basically I need to get 01, 02, 03 instead of 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2017, but im working on SSMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can left pad with this logic:

```
select right('0' + datename(week, date), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the function [`FORMAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
FORMAT(DATEPART(WEEK, your_date), '00')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `case when length()` to do that

```
  Select case when 
   length( DATEPAR(WEEK,DATE)) <2
    then '0'||DATEPAR(WEEK,DATE) else
      DATEPAR(WEEK,DATE)  end
    From table
```